# Execute JS in sharepoint display template

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

In my sharepoint list, I am dealing with items that should have attachments. I customized the template so that it would allow me to add attachments, but I see no possibilities to mark attachments as mandatory. I managed to check for attachments with the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function PreSaveAction() 
            {
                        var elm = document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsTable&quot;);
                        if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsRow&quot;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;
                            alert(&quot;Please attach Documents&quot;);
                            return false ;
                        }
                        else { return true ;}
            }
</script>
```

but I was only able to use it in a custom form (not the template). Since the template is used for pretty much any interaction with the list, I want to use it and would like to execute the js code after the template has loaded. The template is referenced in between the tags `<ZoneTemplate>` and `</ZoneTemplate>`. There's much more code inside that form, but sharepoint-designer won't let me edit anything apart the stuff between those two tags.

It's really frustrating, because I seem to miss an obvious point. Hope I delivered enough information as I am not used to work with sharepoint and it's forms and templates for them...

Answer (score 0):

When you need to add a JavaScript to a list form, you can browse to the form directly. For example, if your list is called MyList, then the new item form would be at http://url/Lists/MyList/newform.aspx and the edit form would be at EditForm.aspx.  Browse to the page or pages where you want to insert your javascript code, then under Site Actions, click Edit Page.  Add a Content Editor Web Part and either insert the javascript directly into the HTML of the content editor web part or add a link to an HTML file that has the javascript.

As for marking an attachment as mandatory, you may just need to include some wording to the form that will instruct the user to click Attach File button.  Maybe something like this that would add a row to the bottom of the form table

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addRow() {
  var required = document.createTextNode("*");
  var table = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-formtable")[0];
  var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.setAttribute("class","ms-formlabel");
  td1.setAttribute("vAlign","top");
  var h31 = document.createElement("h3");
  h31.setAttribute("class","ms-standardheader");
  var text1 = document.createTextNode("Attachment");
  h31.appendChild(text1);
  var span1 = document.createElement("span")
  span1.setAttribute("class","ms-formvalidation");
  span1.setAttribute("title","This is a required field");
  span1.appendChild(required);
  h31.appendChild(span1);
  var td1.appendChild(h31);
  var tr.appendChild(td1);

  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td2.setAttribute("class","ms-formbody");
  td2.setAttribute("vAlign","top");
  var text2 = document.createTextNode("Click the Attach File button in the ribbon to add an attachment");
  var td2.appendChild(text2);
  var tr.appendChild(td2);      

  var tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }

</script>
```

This is pretty ugly and can be simplified with jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
  var h3 = $('<h3 class="ms-standardheader">Attachment</h3>').append('<span class="ms-formvalidation">*</span>');
  var td1 = $("<td></td>").append(h3);
  var td2 = $("<td>Click the Attach File button in the ribbon to add an attachment</td>");
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>").append(td1);
  $(tr).append(td2); 
  $(".ms-formtable").first().find("tbody").first().append(tr);
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind this is untested and probably has some bugs in it.